# What's the performance impact of converting between `DataFrame`, `RDD` and back?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

While my first instinct is to use `DataFrames` for everything, it's just not possible -- some operations are clearly easier and / or better performing as `RDD` operations, not to mention certain APIs like `GraphX` only work on `RDDs`.

I seem to be spending a lot of time these days converting back and forth between `DataFrames` and `RDDs` -- so what's the performance hit? Take `RDD.checkpoint` -- there's no `DataFrame` equivalent, so what happens under the hood when I do:

```
val df = Seq((1,2),(3,4)).toDF("key","value")
val rdd = df.rdd.map(...)
val newDf = rdd.map(r => (r.getInt(0), r.getInt(1))).toDF("key","value")
```

Obviously, this is a trivally small example, but it would be great to know what happens behind the scene in the conversion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's look at `df.rdd` first. This is defined as:

```
lazy val rdd: RDD[Row] = {
  // use a local variable to make sure the map closure doesn't capture the whole DataFrame
  val schema = this.schema
  queryExecution.toRdd.mapPartitions { rows =>
    val converter = CatalystTypeConverters.createToScalaConverter(schema)
    rows.map(converter(_).asInstanceOf[Row])
  }
}
```

So firstly, it runs `queryExecution.toRdd`, which basically prepares the execution plan based on the operators used to build up the DataFrame, and computes an `RDD[InternalRow]` that represents the outcome of plan.

Next these `InternalRow`s (which are only for internal use) of that RDD will be mapped to normal `Row`s. This will entail the following for each row:

```
override def toScala(row: InternalRow): Row = {
  if (row == null) {
    null
  } else {
    val ar = new Array[Any](row.numFields)
    var idx = 0
    while (idx < row.numFields) {
      ar(idx) = converters(idx).toScala(row, idx)
      idx += 1
    }
    new GenericRowWithSchema(ar, structType)
  }
}
```

So it loops over all elements, coverts them to 'scala' space (from Catalyst space), and creates the final row with them. `toDf` will pretty much do these things in reverse.

This all will indeed have some impact on your performance. How much depends on how complex these operations are compared to the things you do with the data. The bigger possible impact however will be that Spark's Catalyst optimizer can only optimize the operations between the conversions to and from RDDs, rather than optimize the full execution plan in its whole. It would be interesting to see which operations you have trouble with, I find most things can be done using basic expressions or UDFs. Using modules that only work on RDDs is a very valid use case though!

Comment: Shouldn't the use of UDF inside DataFrame code add just as much performance overhead as adding RDD code? I thought UDF also require converting from Catalyst space to scala space and back?