# What are the ways to check if DataFrames are empty other than doing a count check in Spark using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, nullpointerexception, apache-spark-sql

```
if(df.count()== 0){
    System.out.println("df is an empty dataframe");
 }
```

The above is a way to check if a DataFrame is empty or not without getting a 
null pointer exception.

Is there any other best way to do so in Spark as I am worried that if the DataFrame df gets millions of records, the above statement will be taking a long time to get executed.

Comment: The above code will get a NullPointerException if df is not a valid object; but generally `Object.count()` is an inexpensive call.

Comment: Yes, df is declared and initialised properly as a DataFrame. But the scenario is it can be both having values and it can also be empty/null.

Answer (score 3):

I recently come across one such scenario. The following are some of the ways to check if a `dataframe` is empty.

- df.count() == 0
- df.head().isEmpty
- df.rdd.isEmpty
- df.first().isEmpty

Although it is better to avoid `count()` since it is more expensive. However there might be some situations where you are very certain that the `dataframe` would have either a single row or no record at all (For ex: Executing a `max()` function in an Hive query). In such situations, it is okay to use `count()`.

Comment: Did df.head().isEmpty, df.rdd.isEmpty or df.first().isEmpty  threw any exception ?

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: depending on your dataset size, you may want to avoid conversion to RDD: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37090151

Answer (score 1):

Taking the count can be slower. Instead you can just check if the head element is not empty.

```
df.head(1).isEmpty
```

Add an exception handling to this as it will throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException` if df is empty.

Update: Check out [How to check if spark dataframe is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707620/how-to-check-if-spark-dataframe-is-empty)