# DataFrame.count() == 0 Vs DataFrame.rdd.isEmpty(): please compare for execution speed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`DataFrame.count()` requires materializing the query which is costly.  Is there a non-negligible cost [of materialization] to  `DataFrame.rdd` and how does that compare to the former?

Is the latter faster to execute?

Comment: What is your definition of better? Memory, speed, easy to maintain, compatibility and so on.... It is difficult to answer correctly a question with the word _better_ without context.

Comment: It is still asking for opinions `better`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `.isEmpty()` is best. Its shorter and less error prone.

### Update

Spark code explains in much better way!! in RDD class `isEmpty()` is

```
def isEmpty(): Boolean = withScope {
  partitions.length == 0 || take(1).length == 0
}
```

Comment: Conversion to RDD is not free: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37090151

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way should be:

```
datset.limit(1).take(1).length > 0
```

This is similar approach to `RDD`'s `isEmpty`, but does not require deserialization like call to `.rdd`

However it's hard to say if it's better in your case - we don't know the requirements

Comment: How is your approach faster than `dataset.limit(1).length==0` ?? The Dataset's take method calls collect() which would be expensive

Comment: @Constantine Yes, it's better to add `limit` before :)

Answer (score 0):

`Spark 3.3` has a new method `dataframe.isEmpty()`. In my brief analysis about an order of magnitude faster for small datasets and similar in performance to the other two options mentioned [`DataFrame.count()` and `DataFrame.rdd.isEmpty()`] for larger datasets.