# Convert dataframe into array of nested json object in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have created dataframe as follows :

```
+----+-------+-------+
| age| number|name   |
+----+-------+-------+
|  16|     12|A      |
|  16|     13|B      |
|  17|     16|E      |
|  17|     17|F      |
+----+-------+-------+
```

How to convert it into following json:

```
{ 
'age' : 16,  
'values' : [{‘number’: ‘12’ , ‘name’ : 'A'},{‘number’: ‘12’ , ‘name’ : 'A'} ] 
},{ 
'age' : 17,  
'values' : [{‘number’: ‘16’ , ‘name’ : 'E'},{‘number’: ‘17’ , ‘name’ : 'F'} ] 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the DF to RDD and apply your transformations:

```py
NewSchema = StructType([StructField("age", IntegerType())
                           , StructField("values", StringType())
                        ])


res_df = df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], ([{'number':row[1], 'name':row[2]}])))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)\
    .map(lambda row: (row[0], json.dumps(row[1])))\
    .toDF(NewSchema)

res_df.show(20, False)
```

Show res_df:

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|age|values                                                      |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|16 |[{"number": 12, "name": "A"}, [{"number": 13, "name": "B"}] |
|17 |[{"number": 17, "name": "F"}, [{"number": 16, "name": "E"}] |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Saving the DF as JSON File:

```py
res_df.coalesce(1).write.format('json').save('output.json')
```

Comment: convert DF to RDD and back to DF can really impact performances

Comment: @Steven Maybe, but I doubt it really impacts the performance because in the background of each DF there are RDDs!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088484/whats-the-performance-impact-of-converting-between-dataframe-rdd-and-back

Answer (score 7):

assuming `df` is your dataframe,

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

new_df = df.select(
    "age",
    F.struct(
        F.col("number"),
        F.col("name"),
    ).alias("values")
).groupBy(
    "age"
).agg(
    F.collect_list("values").alias("values")
)

new_df.toJSON()
# or
new_df.write.json(...)
```

Comment: If you have 'Null' Value in our data then how to handle with using F.struct
because if we use above script then it removing null values cell

Comment: @Amol it removes only null grouping keys ... which means `age=Null`. Do you think OP has this case? or are you just pointing out some missing limiting case which may simply not occures in OP's case ?