# how to write output in nested json using pyspark in aws glue

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I want to write output in nested JSON using pyspark in AWS glue. I have done the following steps :

I used below pyspark code in AWS glue like so

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = dynJoin, mappings = [("patientid", "decimal(19,0)", 
 "patientid", "decimal(19,0)"),("last_name", "string", "last_name", "string"),("first_name", "string", 
 "first_name", "string"),("middle_name", "string", "middle_name", "string"),("prefix", "string", 
 "prefix", "string"),("suffix", "string", "suffixe", "string"),("street_address_1", "string", 
 "street_address_1", "string"), ("street_address_2", "string", "street_address_2", "string"), ("zip", 
 "string", "zip", "string"),   ("city", "string", "city", "string"),("country", "string", "country", 
 "string"), ("group_name", "string", "group_name", "string"),  ("group_id", "string", "group_id", 
 "string"),("current_member_id", "decimal(19,0)", "current_member_id", "decimal(19,0)")], 
 transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

def MergeAddress(rec):

  del rec["street_address_1"]
  del rec["street_address_2"]
  del rec["zip"]
  del rec["city"]
  del rec["country"]
  return rec

mapped_dyF =  Map.apply(frame = applymapping1, f = MergeAddress)
```

#### And output is :-

```
{"patientid":8002,"Address":{"Array":["18 Orchard Avenue",null,"19001","Abington",null]},"group_id":"OLRX","group_name":"OLR Executive","current_member_id":1000434787}
{"patientid":8001,"Address":{"Array":["333 Oak Street",null,"34801","Bradenton",null]},"group_id":"OLRX","group_name":"OLR Executive","current_member_id":1222333444}
{"patientid":8001,"Address":{"Array":["102 North Main Street","Suite 41","32801","Orlando",null]},"group_id":"OLRX","group_name":"OLR Executive","current_member_id":1222333444}
{"patientid":8003,"Address":{"Array":[null,null,null,null,null]},"group_id":"OLRX","group_name":"OLR Executive","current_member_id":12288889444}
```

However, the output needs to be in the below format

```
{"patientid":8001,
"Address":
[{"street_address_1":"333 Oak Street","street_address_2":null,"zip":"34801","city":"Bradenton","country":null},
{"street_address_1":"102 North Main Street","street_address_2":"Suite 41","zip":"32801","city":"Orlando","country":null}
]
,"group_id":"OLRX","group_name":"OLR Executive","current_member_id":1222333444
}
```

Comment: Are you sure json is the format you want to go with? If your going through the effort of using a glue job, if its for data science/warehousing purposes your better off converting it to Parquet, Else depending on your file size / library dependencies you could just use a lambda for this.

Comment: @pkarfs : Thanks for the details , but as per requirement I have to use json format, can you provide more details on lambda function usage

Comment: can you update the input data and required output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704434/convert-dataframe-into-array-of-nested-json-object-in-pyspark

Comment: above link helped to achieve the result