# How to overwrite pyspark DataFrame schema without data scan?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37090151/1661491. Let's assume I have a pyspark DataFrame with certain schema, and I would like to overwrite that schema with a new schema that I **know** is compatible, I could do:

```
df: DataFrame
new_schema = ...

df.rdd.toDF(schema=new_schema)
```

Unfortunately this triggers computation as described in the link above. Is there a way to do that at the metadata level (or lazy), without eagerly triggering computation or conversions?

Edit, note:

- the schema can be arbitrarily complicated (nested etc)
- new schema includes updates to description, nullability and additional metadata (bonus points for updates to the type)
- I would like to avoid writing a custom query expression generator, **unless** there's one already built into Spark that can generate query based on the schema/`StructType`

Comment: How much are you trying to change?  Can it be achieved by `cast` or `F.struct` on specific attributes?

Comment: @Emma thanks for the comment. `cast`/`struct` or constructing `select` statements etc, is not sth I would like to do. I know my schema is compatible and I would like to know if I can do a "zero cost" swap of the schema.

Comment: imho a simple [select](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select.html) should do it. Any computations that might be triggered by `select` won't add an extra Spark stage, so for all practical purposes you could safely ignore them. Depending on the transformations before the `select`, probably an extra [cache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache.html) should be added before.

Comment: @werner what if the schema is potentially **very** complicated, and the changes include changes to field descriptions and some safe nullability/type upgrades? Would that really be "simple"?

Comment: I _believe_ that it should be possible, but I am unsure about the nullability.

Comment: @werner thanks for your input, sure it *might* be possible to generate such a `select` expression but I would prefer to avoid writing such a query generator. It might be quite a bit of work to support arbitrary schema (nesting and metadata: nullability, description and arbitrary fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up diving into this a bit myself, and I'm curious about your opinion on my workaround/POC. See https://github.com/ravwojdyla/spark-schema-utils. It transforms expressions, and updates attributes.

Let's say I have two schemas, first one without any metadata, let's call to `schema_wo_metadata`:

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "oa",
      "nullable": false,
      "type": {
        "containsNull": true,
        "elementType": {
          "fields": [
            {
              "metadata": {},
              "name": "ia",
              "nullable": false,
              "type": "long"
            },
            {
              "metadata": {},
              "name": "ib",
              "nullable": false,
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "type": "struct"
        },
        "type": "array"
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "ob",
      "nullable": false,
      "type": "double"
    }
  ],
  "type": "struct"
}
```

Second one with extra metadata on the inner (`ia`) field and outer (`ob`), let's call it `schema_wi_metadata`

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "oa",
      "nullable": false,
      "type": {
        "containsNull": true,
        "elementType": {
          "fields": [
            {
              "metadata": {
                "description": "this is ia desc"
              },
              "name": "ia",
              "nullable": false,
              "type": "long"
            },
            {
              "metadata": {},
              "name": "ib",
              "nullable": false,
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "type": "struct"
        },
        "type": "array"
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "this is ob desc"
      },
      "name": "ob",
      "nullable": false,
      "type": "double"
    }
  ],
  "type": "struct"
}
```

And now let's say I have a dataset with the `schema_wo_metadata` schema, and want to swap the schema with `schema_wi_metadata`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row, DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType


# I assume these get generate/specified somewhere
schema_wo_metadata: StructType = ...
schema_wi_metadata: StructType = ...

# You need my extra package
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.github.ravwojdyla:spark-schema-utils_2.12:0.1.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Dummy data with `schema_wo_metadata` schema:
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[Row(oa=[Row(ia=0, ib=1)], ob=3.14),
                                 Row(oa=[Row(ia=2, ib=3)], ob=42.0)],
                           schema=schema_wo_metadata)

_jdf = spark._sc._jvm.io.github.ravwojdyla.SchemaUtils.update(df._jdf, schema.json())
new_df = DataFrame(_jdf, df.sql_ctx)
```

Now the `new_df` has the `schema_wi_metadata`, e.g.:

```py
new_df.schema["oa"].dataType.elementType["ia"].metadata
# -> {'description': 'this is ia desc'}
```

Any opinions?

Comment: Posted this at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38904, please consider +1 if you would find this useful as well.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/37011 should hopefully address this problem/question in spark itself.

Answer (score 0):

FYI quick update, this functionality was added to Spark via https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/37011 and will be released in version 3.4.0.